# How can I change the shortcut CTRL + ALT + D (Duplicate Line) from Cnpack plugin?

Tags: delphi, plugins

It there a way to change the "Duplicate line" shortcut from the [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) plugin?

Original:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

I want it to change to:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: Why not asking at [their official forums](http://bbs.cnpack.org/forumdisplay.php?fid=25)?

Comment: I tried but I didn't receive the new account validation email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit this option you just need to do a right click somewhere in the `IDE editor` to show up the editor context menu. There navigate to the entry `CnPack Editor Menu` to open its sub menu. There navigate to `Others` to open the submenu, too, and finally click on `Options...`.

[image: CnPack IDE editor context menu]

In the following dialog window you can select (if not already) the line containing "Duplicate" to then click on the below edit field next to "Shortcut", where you finally can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. Close the dialog window with a click on `Ok` and you're done.

[image: Source Block Tools Hotkey Configuration dialog of CnPack plugin]